# Translated messages inside define()

Tags: php, mysql

I save my translated messages into a php file and inside a

```
define("TEXT", "text");
```

The thing is when i  have a text that shows:

```
We have 30 users online.
```

and a user translates this message to his own language how am I supposed to show the users online when I get the translated text from the define variable?

For example, if the user translates the text to `We have % users online`.

Then I have in the php language file this:

```
define("USERS_ONLINE", "We have % users online");
```

Should I break the string and replace % with my total online users variable?  Should I do the same with even more variables if needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use printf-like syntax instead:

```
define("USERS_ONLINE", "We have %s users online");
echo sprintf(USERS_ONLINE, 30);
```

Then you can have multiple variables in the string:

```
define("USERS_ONLINE", "We have %s users online since %s");
echo sprintf(USERS_ONLINE, 30, $date);
```

Comment: so this can be used for multiple variables inside this define? for example we have % users only where % are active and % log in every day.

Comment: where obviously 30 can be a variable as well... so i think i got it sorted out.big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
$users_online = 30;
echo str_replace( '%' , $users_online , USERS_ONLINE );
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: what if i want to use more %?